# Refresh QWidget Subclass entirely

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a class that Extends QWidget and this class contains multiple child's(QWidget, QLabel).

in the __init__ function of this class, I instantiate the View and fill the labels all of that works fine from another data source object from a singleton class.

now the problem is that I want when I change the value of the data source object the UI should reflect it.

I already tried

```
self.update()
```

but not working.

```
class HomeInterface(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None):
        super(HomeInterface, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, parent.width() - 30 - 30, 500))
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground)       # Used For Setting Style on Super Class
        self.setObjectName("HomeInterface")
        self.setStyleSheet(Styles.HOME_INTERFACE)

        self.__createUI()

    def __createUI(self):
        builderWidget: QWidget = QWidget(self)
        builderWidget.setGeometry(20, 30, self.width() - 20 - 20, 50)

        myLabel: QLabel = QLabel(parent=builderWidget)
        myLabel.setText(myCustomClass.getInstance().getMyTextValue())

        myEditBtn: QPushButton = QPushButton(parent=builderWidget)
        myEditBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.__changeVarValue())

    def __changeVarValue(self):
        myCustomClass.getInstance().setMyTextValue("New Text Value")

    #TODO the UI Should reflect the changes in the variable
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: the above is the example!!!!!!

Comment: Please avoid the abuse of "!", It seems that he is yelling at us and it is not necessary to do so. That code may be an example for you but it is not enough for the community since we require an MRE. Read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: sorry for the impression given, that was not my intention, i am just new and "!" i was wondering what else can i do, i will follow the guide u sent and i will update accordingly